# How to do multi-level sort on a List of a class with multiple variables

Tags: c#, list, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a class called Movies with the following variables declared:

```
string Title;
string Plot;
string MPAA;
string Certification;
string[] Genres;
```

I create a List of Movies with the following code:

```
Movie m = new Movie(strTitle, strPlot, strMPAA, strCertification, strArrGenres);
MovieList.Add(m);
```

I'm now trying to figure out the best way to sort the list.  I need to do two sorts, the first is a simple Sort by Title.  I attempted to use LINQ, but I can't figure out how to access the variable within the Movie correctly.

The second one will be more tricky.  I need to sort by Genre THEN Title.  Each movie of course can have multiple Genres, and I know I will end up with multiple movies since the movie will be in each Genre.

Comment: Do these sorts need to be *in place* or do you want to leave the list itself alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand how you want to sort by Genres if they are contained inside the movies, maybe you want to filter by genre and then sort by title?

```
    class Movie
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string[] Genres { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var movies = new List<Movie>();
        movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Pulp Fiction", Genres = new string[] { "Crime", "Thriller" } });
        movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Back to the Future", Genres = new string[] { "Adventure", "Sci-Fi" } });
        movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "The Dark Knight", Genres = new string[] { "Action", "Crime" } });

        var byTitle = from m in movies orderby m.Title select m;

        var crimeMovies = from m in movies where m.Genres.Contains("Crime") orderby m.Title select m;
    }
```

EDIT: Selecting movies with genre and ordering by Genre then Title (as per comment):

```
        var distinctGenres = from m in movies
                             from genre in m.Genres
                             group genre by genre into genres
                             select genres.First();                          

        var moviesWithGenre = from g in distinctGenres
                              from m in movies
                              where m.Genres.Contains(g)
                              orderby g, m.Title
                              select new { Genre = g, Movie = m };

        foreach (var m in moviesWithGenre)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Genre: "+ m.Genre + " - " + m.Movie.Title);
        }
```

Output:

```
Genre: Action - The Dark Knight
Genre: Adventure - Back to the Future
Genre: Crime - Pulp Fiction
Genre: Crime - The Dark Knight
Genre: Sci-Fi - Back to the Future
Genre: Thriller - Pulp Fiction
```

Comment: I think using your method for the genres will be what I will need to do.  I was HOPING I could do a quick/easy sort and a get list that would have the genre at the top level, and list of movies in that genre under it, next genre etc.  I think if I can get a list of Genres from all the movies, I can use a loop to get a list of movies in each one and process them that way.  Have a query for pulling all the genres out? :)

Answer (score 8):

```
MovieList.OrderBy(m => m.Title)
```

and

```
MovieList.OrderBy(m => m.Genre).ThenBy(m => m.Title)
```

should do it.

Use `.OrderByDescending()` and `.ThenByDescending()` if you want either sort to be descending